# The proper way to interpret $min_{\mathbf{u}}g_i(\mathbf{u}) \hspace{0.2 cm}subject||\mathbf{u}|| = \beta_{t_i}$

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

The answer to this question is probably quite easy but I want to make sure I get this right as I'm not that comfortable with these kinds of expressions yet such that I can read it smoothly. The question concerns the following expression. (Do we even call this an an expression, what should it be called?)

[Figure of the following expression: $min_{\mathbf{u}}g_i(\mathbf{u}) \hspace{0.2 cm} subject||\mathbf{u}|| = \beta_{t_i}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tvn6.png)

My current interpretation is as follows: "Choose u such that the function $g_i(\mathbf{u})$ is minimized, where $||\mathbf{u}||$ has to be equal to $\beta_{t_i}$." Is this a correct interpretation? You can be as nitty picky as you like as to where it could improve or if it is just plain wrong. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Not quite, what you are describing is the argmin. With just a min, this says "what is the minimum possible value of $g_{i}(u)$ when the inputs are constrained to have $||u|| = \beta_{t_i}$. The "argmin" asks for the input $u$ (the "argument") that achieves this minimum value.

Comment: Another example: max age(human) subject to "human is living" asks for how old the oldest living person on earth is. argmax age(human) subject to "human is living" will tell you who the oldest person actually is.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon Thank for the clear example!